# error "sh: 1: read: Illegal option -d" when using here-document in system command run from Python

Tags: python, bash, heredoc

I'm running a Bash system command from within Python and have encountered this problem when using `read` to define a here-document in the command:

```
import os
text     = "~|||-:this is text:-|||~"
fileName = "sound.wav"
command  =\
    "IFS= read -d \'\' text <<EOF\n" +\
    text + "\n" +\
    "EOF\n" +\
    "echo \"${text}\" | text2wave -scale 1 -o " + fileName
os.system(command)
```

Could you help me figure out how to fix this?

---

Here is a slightly simplified version:

```
import os
text     = "~|||-:this is text:-|||~"
command  =\
    "IFS= read -d \'\' text <<EOF\n" +\
    text + "\n" +\
    "EOF\n" +\
    "echo \"${text}\""                        
os.system(command)
```

I wanted to make clear in the one above that I'd be using pipes. When I run this, I get the following error:

sh: 1: read: Illegal option -d

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do all that in shell. Python can write directly to the standard input of the process that will run `text2wave`. Here's an example using the `subprocess` module.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["text2wave", "-scale", "1", "-o", filename], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(text + "\n")
p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way to do this would be using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), either by specifying `stdin` to [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) or by using [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Also, `-d` might not be a valid option in your version of `read`. What does `help [r]ead` tell you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem lies with the way ```read``` is being used in the shell being called I think, not with my not using ```subprocess```.

I would use ```subprocess```, but implementing pipes in it takes a lot of code and I'm going to be using multiple pipes. It is far more concise to use pipes with the ```os.system``` approach.